# Separating out a subquery into its own SELECT statement

Tags: mysql, subquery

I'm working through some old code (not mine) and I need to optimise the following query because it is taking a long time to complete. My guess is the subquery is causing it

```
UPDATE topic a, cycle c
SET a.cycleId = c.id
WHERE a.id = 1
AND ((c.year * 100) + c.sequence) = (
                SELECT MIN((`year` * 100) + sequence)
                FROM cycle c2
                WHERE c2.groupId = a.groupId)
```

I was thinking of selecting the cycleId (c.id) in a separate query before the update statement but I am having problems separating it. So far I have the following but I haven't accounted for the `(c.year * 100) + c.sequence)` and have to be honest I'm not sure what that is doing!

```
SELECT c.id
FROM cycle c
LEFT JOIN topic a ON c.groupId = a.groupId
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

Comment: Your query has a syntax error (comma after `c.id`). Is this the actual query?

Comment: @Denis edited. It's not the actual query I simplified it.

Comment: The hidden question was: are you updating c as well? If not, chances are the query is needlessly writing c where applicable. Use this instead: `UPDATE topic a SET a.cycleId = c.id FROM cycle c ...`.

Comment: @Denis hmm I tried that but it gave me an SQL error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my workaround for time being. Get the result from:

```
SELECT MIN((`year` * 100) + sequence)
FROM cycle c
INNER JOIN topic a ON c.groupId = a.groupId
WHERE a.id = 1;
```

and use in the main query:

```
UPDATE topic a, cycle c
SET a.cycleId = c.id
WHERE a.id = 1
AND ((c.year * 100) + c.sequence) = [result]
```